# Аналог root.after() в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, циклы, qtimer

Есть ли аналог функции `root.after()` в библиотеке *PyQt*?

Если есть, то какой?

Если же нет, то как можно осуществить циклический вызов определенной функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс **`QTimer`** предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

```
...
    self.timer = QTimer()                         
    self.timer.setInterval(1000)                # Миллисекунды  
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onClicked)    
    self.timer.start()

def onClicked(self):  
    ...
```